# Did I use the 'no longer needed' flag correctly in this case? Why was it declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

It's all about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53811599/dynamic-button-to-fit-the-area-size).

The OP posted some code. Then, a user [added an incorrect tag in this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/53811599/2). The question is actually about **Windows Forms**, not **WPF** (as you can read in the comments - it was later confirmed by the OP).

I first saw the code and the **WPF** tag, then posted a comment that the OP uses a wrong approach for WPF. Then, another user posted a similar comment with a little bit more explanation. Both comments were upvoted, because they actually make sense for WPF.

Some time later, a comment appeared:

> Someone (not the OP) added a WPF tag. That Button definition is for a WinForms Button.

I quickly realized that my comment is not appropriate anymore. Yes, the code for **Windows Forms** and **WPF** can be very similar, so I relied on the tag and didn't check the actual code. Knowing that, I deleted my comments as not relevant.

Then, I flagged the mostly upvoted comment from that user explaining about WPF with the 'no longer needed' flag. This comment is actually not needed because it's about a different framework. But since the comment is highly upvoted, it could be misleading for other readers. Furthermore, the suggested solution cannot be implemented in **Windows Forms** at all.

My flag was declined, however. Why? Did I use that 'no longer needed' reason in a wrong way? If yes, what should have been done instead?

Comment: Better to be safe and custom mod flag to explain things to the flag-handling mod. They can't guess your reasoning from the flag, and without additional context the comment would look fine.

Comment: NLN flags are handled quickly and in masse. If you need to provide more context or the handling would require the mod to take a deeper look, it's not a great flag to raise.

Comment: Pretend you see the comment you flagged in isolation (so no further context available). If it is not obvious from the comment it is no longer needed, use a custom mod flag.

Comment: There were rather a lot of terribly confused users involved with that question.  You can't really expect a mod to be less confused, given that 5 users were so confused that they voted that comment as helpful.  It also had a WPF answer, albeit that the poster didn't keep it around for long.  But realistically it is just another entry in the [wpf] vs [winforms] jihad. [winforms] programmers merely try to get the job done, [wpf] programmers strive for a heaven with 72 buttons :)